# Python-http.server - Read entire raw http weft

Tags: python, python-3.x, scapy, httpserver

I created a HTTP server, using Python3 and the http.server module:

```
from http.server import BaseHTTPRequestHandler

class MyHandler(BaseHTTPRequestHandler):

    def do_GET(self):
        # Manage GET query

    def do_POST(self):
        # This is where I need help
        self.send_response(200)
        self.send_header('Content-type', 'text/html')
        self.end_headers()

if __name__ = '__main__':
    # Run the server
```

What I would like is to read the POST query (from the client). I mean the entire raw query, in hexadecimal for example.

I tried with Scapy (it is installed), but:

```
from scapy.all import *

ImportError: No module named 'scapy'
```

I hope it is clear. 
So, if you have any idea, it would really help me.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My bad. Actually my code was good, but my test was not.

So, I saw it on another post, the following is the code to get your data (not the entire request):

```
data = self.rfile.read(int(self.headers.get('Content-length')))
```